# Using if clause inside Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net, textmatching

I am currently coding a .net windows app using vb.net.

I am trying to pass a regular expression to `Regex.Match` to extract certain texts from an article. How do I write an if condition within a regular expression? I read [this regular expression cheat sheet](http://iulitab.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/regularexpressionscheatsheetv2.png), according to which a condition can be stated using `<?()>`, but no example was given.

For example, I have following text:

```
"Mary have banana. Mary have apple. Mary have NO pear."
```

I can use the following expression to take out (1) `banana`, (2) `apple`, and (3) `NO pear`:

```
mary have (.+?\.)+?
```

But if I want to extract only the fruits that `mary` has, namely (1) `banana` and (2) `apple`, I guess I would need to add a condition in the `(.+?\.)+?` part, right? How do I list the condition in a regular expression?

Please assist, thank you!

Comment: You're story is a bit vage. Could you give concrete examples of what should and what shouldn't match?

Comment: from the line of text, the expression should match (1)banana (2)apple... pear should not be matched as it is preceded by the word "NO"... ie: there should not have the word "NO" between the word "have" and fruit.

Comment: Your example is broken English; it is full of grammatical mistakes. Since those mistakes may be crucial in determining the regex, I thought it is better to confirm whether the mistakes are intentional. (1) English proper names start with a capital, so `mary` is usually spelled `Mary`. Does your example really have `mary`? (2) The third singular present form is `has`, not `have`. Does your example have `have`? (3) Banana and apple are countable nouns, so the correct form is `a banana`, `an apple`. Does you example really have `banana`, `apple`?

Comment: oh... the example (mary...apple...) given are just used to show the generic repeating patten that the text contains... that are not the actual data... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this here:

```
Mary\shave\s(?!NO)(\S*)
```

You can try it online here: [regexr.com?2thid](http://regexr.com?2thid)

The first part is a negative lookahead assertion, that means this regex will not match if there is "Mary have NO". Otherwise it will put the word after "Mary have" into the first capturing group.

[Here in the Perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Conditional-expressions) (assuming its the same for .net) the condition part is explained, but I think my solution is simpler.

Comment: It would be better to limit the negative look ahead to just the "NO" to prevent excess backtracking. Also, you can invert the `\s` simply by capitalising it. `Mary\shave\s(?!NO)(\S*)`

Comment: thanks for ur ans... i have used it for my program and i think it is working correctly...

check with ur... for <space>, it is the same if i key in " " rather than \s? i.e.:Mary have (?!NO)(\S*)

Comment: @huhoo \s is a whitespace character that means everything that produces whitespace e.g. " " or tab. \S is NOT a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided solutions for your specific case, so I'll just focus on the "if clause" mentioned in the heading.

.NET supports conditionals using the following pattern.

```
(?(bob)[a-z]+|[0-9]+)
```

The regular expression will first try to match the text expression (the portion in the inner parentheses), if it matches then the over all expression will try to match using the sub expression before the pipe (`[a-z]+`) otherwise it will try to match using the sub expression after the pipe (`[0-9]+`).

Having said all that, I think the negative look ahead as suggested by stema would be a better fit for what you are trying to do.

Note: the "test" portion can also use any of the zero-width assertions such as the negative look behind.

```
(?(?<!\s)[a-z]+|[0-9]+)
```

Of-course a zero-width look ahead is redundant as the "test" expression is always considered zero-width.

Comment: +1 I never used conditions within regex before, but good to know thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you can use without the hassle of regular expressions, but I can only answer in C#

> ```
>     string sentence = "Mary have banana Mary have apple Mary have NO pear";
>     if (sentence.Contains("banana"))
>     {
>         string x= sentence.Remove(sentence.IndexOf("banana"),"banana".Length);
>     }
> ```

Don't laugh XD just a speedfix. Just rinse and repeat for the rest of the items

Comment: I can't use .contains("banana")... the fruit names are not fixed... only the patten (mary have ... mary have NO ... mary have ...) are fixed

Answer (score 0):

then try using the `.Split()` method.  the split will probably look something like thisstring

```
sentence = "Mary have banana Mary have apple Mary have NO pear"; 
string[] brokenUp = sentence.Split(
      new String[] 
      { 
          "first fruit as string variable", 
          "second fruit as string variable", 
          "third fruit as string variable" 
      }, 
      StringSplitOptions.None
);
string newSentence = null;
for (int i = 0; i < brokenUp.Length; i++)
{
    newSentence += brokenUp[i];
}
```

Comment: pardon me, but I'm way too lazy to use regular expressions. I manipulate strings . there Is a way to extract "mary have" "Mary have " "Mary Don't have".  I just don't see where you are trying to get at though.